# Email Parameter In Power BI Report Builder

Tags: parameters, powerbi, powerbi-paginated-reports

So Basically I want to make a parameter in my report in power bi report builder that makes the user enter his email not choose but enter it manually because there is sensitive information that not all the users are allowed to see so how can this be done ?

I added email column in the my data source and added parameter in the query designer but it's shown as a drop down menu and that's not the outcome I want so how to change it to be manually entered instead of drop down ?

Comment: How do you stop other users from accessing other peoples data, if they enter someone else's email. Check out this link https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/how-to-setup-report-parameters-to-default-based-on-user-credentials

Comment: I am asking about Power BI Report Builder not sql server

Comment: The example uses SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS), which PBI Report Builder is based on. It shows a solution to get the report user name and pass it to a query. You need to update your question with a few more details, like data source, how you are getting the data etc. The example I posted should contain enough information using the built in [&userID] to filter your report. Also try here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30400231/filter-ssrs-report-to-current-user

Comment: For your requirement for a none secure approach, where anyone can input any email address try here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45568104/how-to-create-a-textbox-in-ssrs-for-user-entry-as-a-parameter